# 2D long array appending an extra zero to value

Tags: java, arrays

Below is an example of me trying to add some values to a 2D long array. For the 'left' side of the array the values are printed correctly. However the right side seems to print an extra zero onto the [i][1] (right side) values.

Why is this? Is it because I am assigning what really could be an int to a long array or is it just a mistake I have made in my code.

```
public class test {
public static void main (String [] args) {

        int printValue = 3;

        long [] [] programUserID = new long [printValue][printValue];
        for (int i=0; i<printValue; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<printValue; j++) {
                programUserID[i][1] = 666;
            }
            programUserID[i][0] = 1998;
        }

        for (int x=0; x<programUserID.length; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<programUserID.length; y++) {
                System.out.print(programUserID[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
19986660
19986660
19986660
```

I would like to be able to use the 2D long array and be able to assign all the [i][1] (right side) values 0 and increment them from there accordingly.

Comment: `programUserID[i][1] = 666;` - All it does is intitialize [i][1] to 666.

Comment: Please post the desired output alongside with your code.

Comment: refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Comment: @Coffeehouse Coder Thanks for the input. Done

Comment: @Prashant That's not really the problem, is it? Even if the array was of `int` type, the values would still be 0.

Comment: @Coffeehouse Coder Yes it would be. The default value is zero and since the OP has not assigned a value to the last cell of the array, its this value that is being printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extra Zeros are happening because you are creating a third set of values which is not set to a number.

If you just wanted the two values then the code might be something like:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        final int programUsersLength = 3;

        long [] [] programUserID = new long [programUsersLength][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < programUsersLength; i++) {
            programUserID[i][0] = 1998;
            programUserID[i][1] = 666;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < programUserID.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < programUserID[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.print(programUserID[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would love to see `printValue` as final as its value is not being changed. More so, this variable is not required at all as you are using an `int` literal to intitalize your array anyways

Comment: I agree, also should probably name the class Test not test and give the variable a more meaningful name like programUsersLength

Comment: Also would have had an exception because of the change to length of the second dimension...